# How to make default logger file in iPad using jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need to create logger type screen having white background. Firstly I am thinking to prepare with static data. Can you please help me how to do that using jQuery mobile? Actually I need to show server data here now till now I am thinking to only work with static data. How to make this (red round) screen?

[image]

Comment: Is this a UI question (what css rules to use to have the above result) or something else because it's not clear

Comment: No i just wanted to make this screen using jquery mobile with white background and these text

Comment: And what's the problem? Do you have some code?

Comment: i don't under stand how to start .truly speaking i am able to make header but body what to use so that it look like that..

Comment: Can you solve my second issue .i have 3 button on header not on this screen. i want to show pop up on these button but i did this .But i don't understand the size of pop up screen different? setting pop up screen is smaller than plus pop up screen .here is my code.http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/HesVd/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the background to be white you can either add it 
yourself (custom css) and use the keyword !important so it will override jquery mobile,
either add `data-theme="d"` to your `data-role="page"` div

Comment: yes .i understand ..what about the contents (labels) ?is this table view or ?

Comment: If this answers your question please mark as answered. As for the second question, it's a completely different one, so you should create a new question.

Comment: jqm doesn't offer what you want so you will have to style it yourself. It's not that diffucult.

Comment: can you add top two line in with space than after i will use to make full screen?

Comment: I don't understand your last question

Comment: First you go this fiddle than you understand properly http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/HesVd/16/.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31900/discussion-between-user2484319-and-alkis)